# chrome not sending GET request from ajax, works on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, http-get

I am pretty new to web programming specially javascript and other front end logic. I am seeing this weird error where my code works perfectly fine on latest version of Firefox on Windows 10 but does not work on latest version of chrome on Windows 10.

Basically I have a form which consists of two multi select drop down and two buttons. For both these buttons, I send ajax POST request in their click listener with checkbox params to python flask server which in turn creates a file on the server then in success of my POST ajax, I send get request to download the file that I just created. In Firefox and chrome both, my POST calls are going and files are being generated correctly, however get request is not sent by chrome to download the file but firefox is sending correct get request to get the file.

Another weird thing is, chrome does download a file upon get request which it is sending somewhere but it is not reaching my server. I do not see get request in my flask server log from chrome but it does show up for firefox. In both cases files are downloaded but chrome downloads wrong file from some wrong place.

I also tried adding delay on server thinking, file is still being generated when POST request is returned but that also didn't change chrome behaviour.

Below is the snippet of my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/images/main.png">
        <title>Link Curation - Curated Results</title>
        
        <!--  Scripts-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/init.js"></script>
      
        <!-- CSS  -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="static/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        <link href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#progress').hide();
            $('select').material_select();
        
            // Download jsonlines
            $("#jlines").click(function(e){
                // Required for non-chrome browser
                e.preventDefault()
                
                var tags = $('#museums').val();
                var codes = $('#codes').val();
                
                var userObj = new Object();
                userObj.data = {"tags":tags,"codes":codes,"type":"jlines"};
                json_data = JSON.stringify(userObj);
                console.log(json_data);
                var sv = '{{server}}'.concat("/download");
                
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: sv,
                    data: json_data,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#progress').show();
                        document.getElementById("jlines").disabled = true;
                        console.log("downloading...")
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("File Created!");
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        document.getElementById("jlines").disabled = false;
                        window.location.href = "/download?type=jlines";
                    },
                    error: function(xhr){
                        console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' \nStatus Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' \nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
                        Materialize.toast("Something went wrong. Please try again!",5000);
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        document.getElementById("jlines").disabled = false;
                    }
                });
            });
        
            // Download triples
            $("#triples").click(function(e){
                // Required for non-chrome browser
                e.preventDefault()
                
                var tags = $('#museums').val();
                var codes = $('#codes').val();
                
                var userObj = new Object();
                userObj.data = {"tags":tags,"type":"triples"};
                json_data = JSON.stringify(userObj);
                console.log(json_data);
                var sv = '{{server}}'.concat("/download");
                
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: sv,
                    data: json_data,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#progress').show();
                        document.getElementById("triples").disabled = true;
                        console.log("downloading...")
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("File Created!");
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        document.getElementById("triples").disabled = false;
                        window.location.href = "/download?type=triples";
                    },
                    error: function(xhr){
                        console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' \nStatus Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' \nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
                        Materialize.toast("Something went wrong. Please try again!",5000);
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        document.getElementById("triples").disabled = false;
                    }
                });
            });

        });
        </script>
        
        <style>
            #body {
                min-height: calc(100vh - 10px);
            }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>{% include 'header.html' %}</div>
        <div id="body">
        
        <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row center">
                    <br><br>
                    <h5> Download the curated results (Tip: Select ulan to download all data!) </h5>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="header col s12 m4">
                        <select multiple id="museums" >
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose museum(s)</option>
                            {% for tag in keys %}
                                <option value={{tag}}>{{tag}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="header col s12 m4">
                        <select multiple id="codes">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose pair status(s)</option>
                            <option value="3">Match</option>
                            <option value="4">Unmatch</option>
                            <option value="5">Not Sure</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="header col s12 m4">
                        <form name ="download_data">
                            <div id="progress" class="preloader-wrapper small active">
                                <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green-only">
                                    <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                        <div class="circle"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gap-patch">
                                        <div class="circle"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                        <div class="circle"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id = "jlines" type="submit" class="btn" >Jsonlines</button>
                            <button id = "triples" type="submit" class="btn" >Triples</button>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="section no-pad-bot">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row center">
                    <h5>Curated results from all museums will show up below. You can sort them based on the status or URI or even search based on museum.</h5>
                    <br><br>
                    <iframe class="header col s12 light" src="datatable" style="border:0" height="1000" ></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>{% include 'footer.html' %}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Nilay

Comment: I could be blind, but I see no GET request in your code - *edit:* oh, right, you get the result using `window.location.href = ...`

Comment: Yes correct. I also tried sending in traditional ajax way of GET request but that didn't change my output so i settled for one liner which was still doing the same thing.